# Print multiple PDF files on single button click in SharePoint 2010

Tags: pdf

I am new in SharePoint Development. I want to print all selected PDF files on single button click.

The button can be a ribbon button or application page button.
I tried in multiple ways and searched over the internet but didn't find any working solution for me.

Please help me.

Comment: I think you can not do this with standart SharePoint features. Maybe you can try to do this via a custom web part.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out-of-the-box and is actually quite tricky to develop, but not impossible.

I am considering adding this facility to one of my company's products (We create SharePoint PDF Conversion and manipulation software) and it will involve something like the following:

1. Add a button to the SharePoint ribbon using the standard facility for doing this.
2. When clicked send a list of the selected Item IDs to the server using Javascript.
3. On the server merge the files together (our software already has a facility to do this, but you could get a third party .net library for PDF merging)
4. Send the resulting file back to the browser where the user can open the PDF and print it.

The disadvantage of this approach is that, when printed, it will go to the printer as a single job so you cannot control such things as automatic stapling or starting each document  on an odd page (for double sided printing).

Comment: Thanks. I want to print separate files (using JS on client side). What will happen if multiple users will perform the job at the same time?

Comment: Multiple users shouldn't matter unless you write a really bad solution :-). If you just wish to use client side JS then you probably have to use SharePoint's Client Side Object model to load the PDF in an iFrame and then invoke a print command on the Acrobat ActiveX control (There are some security considerations as by default you cannot send things to the printer from JavaScript). I am making this up on the spot, but by Googling for these keywords you should be able to find parts of your solution.